# Jquery-Ui autocomplete skips expressions "+" and "-"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I use Jquery-Ui version 1.12.1 for auto-complete. But it can only autocomplete alphabet-based search but not expressions like '+' and '-'.

Can I add a regular expression inside the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

its functional with text beginning by `+` and `-` using regexp with $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), this function protects the special characters using in regexp, so its possible to use `+-[]() and so on` in search.

```js
var tags = ["c++", "+bonjour", "--learn", "super", "beauty", "wasp", "rubics"];
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(tags, function(item) {
      return matcher.test(item);
    }));
  }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>autocomplete with + and -</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <label for="autocomplete">Select Something </label>
  <input id="autocomplete">


</body>

</html>
```